# Is the PULSE_SERVER environment variable supposed to take an IPv6 address?

Tags: ipv6, pulse-audio

I am currently struggling with Avahi. Before debugging further, I wanted to check the sanity of my Pulseaudio setup, so I commanded 'export PULSE_SERVER=10.4.0.202 && mplayer sound.mp3' which correctly performs the magic of remote sound.

But 'export PULSE_SERVER=2001:470:ca99:4:ba27:ebff:fee2:ada9 && mplayer sound.mp3' ignores the PULSE_SERVER parameter and just plays sound locally - the same behaviour occurs when enclosing the IPv6 address in []. Damn.

The host on which I execute the command and the one where I connect headphones are both on the same Ethernet segment with no router in-between. IPv6 connectivity is fine - at this very moment I am logged on the remote host by SSH over IPv6. No iptables on either host.

So, my question: is the PULSE_SERVER environment variable supposed to take an IPv6 address or is is it restricted to legacy IP addresses ?

Client host is Debian Jessie, pulseaudio 5.0

Server host is Raspbian Wheezy, pulseaudio 2.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct syntax for setting the Pulseaudio server as an IPv6 address is PULSE_SERVER="[2001:470:ca90:4:ba27:ebff:fee2:ada9]" - with both "" and [] !

Problem solved - let the music flow across the IPv6 !

Comment: Although the quotation marks just keep the shell from interpreting the value. They aren’t actually part of the value.

Comment: I should have known better than attempting shell variable assignment eschewing the double quotes... Always use the double quotes !

Comment: @Jean-MarcLiotier Sometimes you need single quotes sometimes you need double quotes. This is one of the cases where it doesn't make a difference whether you use single or double quotes. If there is a `$` sign somewhere in the string it will make a difference whether you use single or double quotes.